# Marking items as selected in Angular directives

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js

I am new to Angular and feel that I'm doing mistakes and reinventing the wheel. Could you please review my code and share your ideas about how it can be improved. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKVYiz)

The problem is very common. I have a list of items (countries) that can be loaded inside a directive controller. I have an `Id` of selected item (selected). I want to select a country when clicked on.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good practice to load countries in the countries directive controller? Or maybe should it be loaded in the `MainCtrl` and bind to directive?
2. If I need only countryId is it good to store only this Id in the `MainCtrl` model? Or maybe should I store the country object with `id` and `name`?
3. How the `countrySelectController` can be improved? Does it smell bad? How should `select()` be organized?

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    country: "USA"
  };
});

app.directive('countrySelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      selected: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'countrySelect.html',
    controller: 'countrySelectController'
  };
});

app.controller('countrySelectController', function($scope) {
  function load(){
    // will be loaded from service
    return [
      {id: 'USA', name: 'United States of America'},
      {id: 'RU', name: 'Russian Federation'},
      {id: 'CHN', name: 'China'}
    ];
  };

  function markAsSelected(countryId){
    angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(country){
      country.selected = country.id === countryId;
    });
  }

  $scope.countries = load();
  markAsSelected($scope.selected);

  $scope.select = function(country){
    $scope.selected = country.id;
    markAsSelected($scope.selected);
  }
});
```

CountrySelect.html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-click="select(country)">
    {{country.id}} - {{country.name}} | {{country.selected}}
  </li>
</ul>
```